# cross compile qt5.5 for Raspbian jessie

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, raspbian

I've been following this guide on how to cross compile QT for raspbian: http://exploreembedded.tumblr.com/post/115333857238/guide-to-cross-compile-qt-54-for-the-raspberry-pi

It's some months old, so certain changes have been made to fit it with Jessie and qt 5.5 instead of Wheezy and qt 5.4. However I've gotten down to the configure and make portion of the guide and I am completely stuck. When running  $make, I'm getting a bunch of these errors:

> .obj/qeasingcurve.o:qeasingcurve.cpp:function easeInOutCirc(double): error: undefined reference to 'sqrt'
>
> .obj/qeasingcurve.o:qeasingcurve.cpp:function easeOutCirc(double): error: undefined reference to 'sqrt'
>
> .obj/qeasingcurve.o:qeasingcurve.cpp:function easeInCirc(double): error: undefined reference to 'sqrt'
>
> .obj/qeasingcurve.o:qeasingcurve.cpp:function easeOutInSine(double): error: undefined reference to 'cos'

By googling, I've gotten some understand as to why this is happening (Looks like math library needs to be linked manually for some unexplained reason), but not as to how I can fix it. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one seemed to know the answer, I found another way of doing it that seems to work with some fiddling instead: https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS